# Windows 8 Kernel-data-inpage-error after every boot

Tags: windows-8, crash

Three days ago, I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8 Pro.

I have updated all drivers from HP and ran all memory/harddisk check programs (F2,F10 in boot)

Still every time computer is turned on it stops 10 seconds after, at the time Win8 light blue logo is on screen with small rotating balls and boot starts again. Then it starts normally and comes user signon screen. When Win8 apps screen opens it tells it crashed during start:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Boot" Guid="{15CA44FF-4D7A-4BAA-BBA5-0998955E531E}" /> 
  <EventID>29</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-02-05T02:57:05.720777100Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>228</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>Koti</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
  <Data Name="FailureStatus">3221225473</Data> 
  <Data Name="FailureMsgId">5773260680888904</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

### System information

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 8 Pro
Version 6.2.9200 Build 9200
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name [REDACTED]
System Manufacturer Hewlett-Packard
System Model    HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  [REDACTED]
Processor   AMD A8-3520M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics, 1600 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Hewlett-Packard F.48, 2012-10-23
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Embedded Controller Version 24.26
BIOS Mode   Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Hewlett-Packard
BaseBoard Model Not Available
BaseBoard Name  Base Board
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  Finland
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.2.9200.16384"
User Name   [REDACTED]
Time Zone   Eastern Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 6.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   5.48 GB
Available Physical Memory   3.71 GB
Total Virtual Memory    11.0 GB
Available Virtual Memory    8.97 GB
Page File Space 5.50 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    No
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem that I had with my laptop. 
Here is the following solution which I learnt from a local laptop servicing center. It may sound crazy but actually worked for me.

1. Check for the bad sectors in your hard disk. Consider replacing it when it reaches above 20.
2. Try to clean up the CPU fan in your laptop.

In most of the windows 8 bsod's this step 2 might be helpful. Because I had lot of dust in that and after cleaning up it is working without any glitches.